# Cannot close a pool while it is connecting?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, settimeout, connection-pooling, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to implement some queries in my server code, but am facing this error:

`setImmediate(callback, new ConnectionError('Cannot close a pool while it is connecting'))`

`ConnectionError: Cannot close a pool while it is connecting`

I checked online and it said to use `mssql.query` instead of a `mssql.timeout` but my code has both so it got me quite confused. I tried to increase the **set timeout** from 500 to 1500 thinking the error was because of that, but it still had crashes.

**An odd thing** is that the server *doesn't always crash*. It just happens *randomly* at times when a query is being executed.

The server essentially sends data for beacons and the floor they are located on.

I've been trying to figure this out for quite sometime now. I would appreciate any help.

Here is the parts where the error is happening:

```
// Handle POST requests for downloading files for beacons
app.post('/beacon', function (req, res) {

    // POST variables
    var auth = req.body.auth;
    var gid = req.body.gid;
    var fno = req.body.fno;

    // Database Information 
    const config = {
        user: 'RANDOM',
        password: auth,
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'beacons',
        "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
        },
        port: 1499
    };

    try{
        // Connect to database
        mssql.connect(config, function (err) {

            // Create request handler and query for files
            var request = new mssql.Request();
            var query = `SELECT beacon_file FROM dbo.beacons WHERE group_id = ${gid} AND floor_num = ${fno}`;

            // Query for file to download
            request.query(query,
            function (err, records) {
                try{
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err;
                    }

                    try {

                        // If there are files associated with the given group ID
                        if (records.rowsAffected != '0'){
                            // Get filename & send for download
                            // NOTE: We can either send a download or send text, not both using the current setup
                            var fileName = 'beaconfiles/' + records.recordset[0].beacon_file;
                            res.download(fileName, function (derr) {
                                if (derr) {
                                    throw(derr);
                                }

                                else {
                                console.log(`Successfully sent ${fileName} for download.`)
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            res.send(`<p>There are no files with that group ID.</p>
                                <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);  
                        }
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(`There was an error:  ${err} `);
                        res.send(`<p>There was an error. Make sure the group ID is correct: ${err}</p>
                            <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>` );
                    }
                }
                catch(err){
                    res.send(`<p>There was an error getting the file: ${err}</p>
                        <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);
                }
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
            mssql.close();
            }, 1500);

        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(`There was an issue connecting to the database, check the authorization: ${err} `);
        res.send(`<p>There was an issue connecting to the database, check the authorization: ${err}</p>
            <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);
    }
});

// Handle POST requests for downloading files for beacons
app.post('/floor', function (req, res) {

    // POST variables
    var auth = req.body.auth;
    var gid = req.body.gid;
    var fno = req.body.fno;

    // Database Information 
    const config = {
        user: 'RANDOM',
        password: auth,
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'beacons',
        "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
        },
        port: 1499
    };

    try{
        // Connect to database
        mssql.connect(config, function (err) {

            // Create request handler and query for files
            var request = new mssql.Request();
            var query = `SELECT floor_file FROM dbo.beacons WHERE group_id = ${gid} AND floor_num = ${fno}`;

            // Query for file to download
            request.query(query,
            function (err, records) {
                try{
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err;
                    }

                    try {

                        // If there are files associated with the given group ID
                        if (records.rowsAffected != '0'){
                            // Get filename & send for download
                            // NOTE: We can either send a download or send text, not both using the current setup
                            var fileName = 'beaconfiles/' + records.recordset[0].floor_file;
                            res.download(fileName, function (derr) {
                                if (derr) {
                                    throw(derr);
                                }

                                else {
                                console.log(`Successfully sent ${fileName} for download.`)
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            res.send(`<p>There are no files with that group ID.</p>
                                <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);  
                        }
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(`There was an error:  ${err} `);
                        res.send(`<p>There was an error. Make sure the group ID is correct: ${err}</p>
                            <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>` );
                    }
                }
                catch(err){
                    res.send(`<p>There was an error getting the file: ${err}</p>
                        <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);
                }
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
            mssql.close();
            }, 1000);

        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(`There was an issue connecting to the database, check the authorization: ${err} `);
        res.send(`<p>There was an issue connecting to the database, check the authorization: ${err}</p>
            <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>`);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a WAG.  Do you need to use an instance ref to the diver like "var sql = require("mssql");"?  I really don't know, but I've seen it this way.  Is it a static vs instance thing?

Comment: So what's with the timeouts around the `mssql.close()` calls? The `connection-pooling` tag suggests that you're trying to use the Connection Pools, so you shouldn't be calling `close()` anyway. Ref: [node-mssql](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/) _Also notice that we do *not* close the global pool by calling `sql.close()` after the query is executed, because other queries may need to be run against this pool and closing it will add additional overhead to running subsequent queries. You should only ever close the global pool if you’re certain the application is finished._

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when trying to execute my procedures *(i have written my procedures in MSSQL, i just need to call it using `exec`)*. Here is my code for the Execute:

```
module.exports.Execute = (sSQL) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(config, err => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);

            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(sSQL, (err, result) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);

                sql.close();

                if (result)
                    resolve(result)
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Looking into [node-mssql](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/) by user [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning), i just delete the `sql.close()` and add `await` based on the docs. And to be sure, I defined a new function called `procedureQueryString` as so:

```
procedureQueryString: (sSQL) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await sql.connect(config, async err => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);

                var request = new sql.Request();
                await request.query(sSQL, (err, result) => {
                    if (err)
                        reject(err);

                    if (result)
                        resolve(result)
                })
            });
        })
    }
```

And it is now working